# Is there any way to check if any or all characters are present in a string in C?

Tags: c, string, char

I was trying to check and see if I give an array of characters - 
like this

```
char  array_values[] = { 'A','B','C','D','a','b','c','d' };
```

and then running a sort of character matching in multiple strings e.g.-

```
....
str1 = 'AACDBACBAabcAcddaAABD'
str2 = 'aacbdAABDCAaDDCBCAabc'
....
```

and then returning a count of each char present in the strings.

I know it's easily done in python, R, perl, but I wanted to figure this out in C.
Maybe something like a regular expression? Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using ANSI C? Because if you're, regular expressions aren't part of ANSI C, and you'll have to use a looping mechanism for that.

Comment: What are you trying to do? for each string `strX`, count how often each of the characters in `array_values` occurs?

Comment: `strpbrk` is an option for the first part.

Comment: I was basically reading in lines from a file, and converting them to a array, since I am interested in a particular set of characters, and if that set was present in that line, count ++

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to do it in C is to count each character regardless of its presence in the `array_values`, then use `array_values` items as indexes into the array of counts to get the results:

```
int count[256];
for (int i = 0 ; i != 256 ; count[i++] = 0);
// The example works with a single string. For multiple strings,
// iterate over the strings from your source in a loop, assigning str
// and incrementing the counts for each of your strings.
char *str = "AACDBACBAabcAcddaAABD";
for (char *p = str ; *p ; count[(unsigned char)*p++]++);
char array_values[] = { 'A','B','C','D','a','b','c','d' };
for (int i = 0 ; i != 8 ; i++) {
    printf("Found '%c' %d times", array_values[i], count[(unsigned char)array_values[i]]);
}
```

Here is a [demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/K8CHln).

Comment: Note: in most implementations, characters are **signed** by default.

Comment: @wildplasser You are right, adding `unsigned` is a good idea. Thanks!

Comment: The way you cast it now it would wrap around to UINT_MAX-something, IMHO. (which would surely crash)

Comment: @wildplasser All C source characters are guaranteed to be positive (i.e. <= 127).

Comment: But the question **was not** about "C source characters". That is something you introduced. And since the characters are stored in a string or array, there could be a 0x80 .. 0xFF somewhere in its contents.